# I have two lists that represents long numbers and i need to find a recursively way to answer which number is bigger

Tags: java, list

I have two lists that each list represent a number from type long.
Every number is saved backwards in each list.meaning: (123 is saved 321)
and I'm trying to find a way to find which list has the biggest number by going only one time on each lists.
I need to do it recursively and i prefer an abstract idea instead of straight up answer.

Comment: Your question is so confusing. Try to fix that. What exactly means 'list represent a long number'? Did not you mean list of numbers (long)? 'Number is saved backwards in each list' - means that you are inserting number at the end of list? 'Which number is bigger...' means which which list has bigger max number?

Comment: yes sir, and i have edit my question.

Comment: @yardentamam I think you meant to say that `123` is saved as `[3, 2, 1]`, right? A `List` of digits in reverse order.

Answer (score 1):

You implement a method with this signature:

```java
int compare(List<Integer> num1, List<Integer> num2, int index)
```

where `num1` and `num2` are your two lists of digits in reverse order, and `index` is the index into the lists to be compared.

You recurse until `index` reaches the end of the longest list, then you compare and return a value like other *compare* methods do (<0, >0, ==0). If the lists are not the same length, and `index` is beyond the end of one of the lists, use a `0` value for the missing digit of that list.

When returning, the recursive caller will check the value and compare digits if the return value is `0`, otherwise just return the return value unchanged.

Comment: i did not completely understand it. 
how can i use an index and for what exactly.
I'm trying to figure out how to stop if the biggest digit is bigger then the other and if not to keep comparing .
thank you for the help.

Comment: @lanz Read the last paragraph. If the return value is not `0`, return it unchanged, i.e. stop comparing. --- How would you keep track of where are are in the recursion if not using an index? `subList()`? Too resource intensive, when a simple index will do.

Comment: I can not understand how can i stop comparing?

Comment: @lanz I already explained, but maybe a third time will do it: When recursive call returns non-zero value, return that immediately, i.e. don't compare the previous digits, i.e. **stop comparing** once a difference has been detected.